# IBM Keyboard Features on Ubuntu How to Fix?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have just migrated to the wonderful world of Linux using Ubuntu and am slowly finding my way around.
I have an IBM KB 9930 raid access keyboard which mostly works OK, apart from some of the ancillary keys like volume, play/pause/ff/rw and the quick keys across the top of the keyboard.
Is there a simple way of configuring it to work on Ubuntu?

Comment: **Anthony:** please [edit] your question and add the output of the keys you want to define.  I've been notified you've tried to answer your own question instead of editing your original question...  Then leave a comment **@Fabby**

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting this as an answer but the comments don't give enough space and mark-up to properly test whether these keys work or not.  If it works, I'll delete this answer and we'll go hunting for what is wrong in software.

**Remember that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> is your friend!** That is the key combination to press to get back here so you can read the rest of the message...

OK?  Got that?  Have it on a Post-It note?

Good! Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and you will se a terminal (a *real* terminal, not `gnome-terminal` or `xterm` that you've used until now...)

Log in by typing your user name and password (no stars or password will be echoed, this is 1970s technology after all) and once you're logged in type the following command:

```
showkey --scancodes
```

Now lightly press and release the <kbd>Esc</kbd> the <kbd>Volume</kbd>, <kbd>Play</kbd>, and all the other keys you want to test...  Then do what you do best for 10 seconds...

If every single key you typed, gave an output on your screen, you're in luck: yes, these can be defined; you should write down the output on a Post-It and leave a comment below with the output...  (no copy-paste back in the '70s!!!  And now that I think of it: no Post-Its either!)